# Can you help me understand the properties and zeros of this function involving square roots terms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, radicals, wolfram-alpha

Consider this function ( I got this when I was solving an another problem)

f(n) =
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left[\left(\frac{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+16008n}}{2n}\right)+\sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+16008n}}{2n}\right)^2\right)-\frac{16008}{\frac{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+16008n}}{2n}}}\right]-n$$

When I searched "f(n)=0" on Wolfram alpha, it shows result: $$ 
n \geq \sqrt[3]{2001}
$$
(That means f(n) has infinitely many zeroes ?)

Since,$$13\geq \sqrt[3]{2001}$$ f(13) should be zero , same for f(14), f(15) and so on...
But when I evaluated f(13) on Wolfram alpha the result was $$5.32907\times10^{-15}$$

I also found that f(n)=0 whenever I plugged $$n \geq 60
$$
Can you help me with these questions.

1. If f(n) really has infinitely many zeroes ?
2. Is f(n) an algebraic function ?
3. Why Wolfram alpha behaves in this way ?

Comment: Your function is written in a ridiculously obscure form for no apparent reason. Why?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I appreciate your feedback. Can you provide more specific feedback on what makes the current form obscure, and perhaps suggest a simpler or more understandable way to express it? I'm eager to learn.

Comment: Asymptotically for large n the [ ] term is $2n$, so that $f(n)$ will go to zero for large n. That doesn't mean it has an infinite number of zeros.

Comment: Please mark the solution below as ANSWERED if it answers your original post.

Comment: I've marked the solution as answered, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bizarrely, this function is indeed identically equal to $0$ for all real numbers $n\ge\sqrt[3]{2001}$. It can be simplified to
$$
\frac14\biggl( -3n + \sqrt{n^2+\frac{16008}n} + \sqrt{10n^2+\frac{16008}n-6n\sqrt{n^2+\frac{16008}n}} \biggr),
$$
which further simplifies to
$$
\frac14\biggl( -3n + \sqrt{n^2+\frac{16008}n} + \sqrt{\Bigl(3n-\sqrt{n^2+\frac{16008}n} \Bigr)^2} \biggr)
$$
and therefore to
$$
\frac14\biggl( -3n + \sqrt{n^2+\frac{16008}n} + \biggl| 3n-\sqrt{n^2+\frac{16008}n} \, \biggr| \biggr),
$$
which finally equals
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac12\biggl( \sqrt{n^2+\frac{16008}n} -3n \biggr), & \text{if } \sqrt{n^2+\frac{16008}n} \ge 3n, \\
0, & \text{if } \sqrt{n^2+\frac{16008}n} \le 3n.
\end{cases}
$$
This last inequality is the source of the changed behavior at $n=\sqrt[3]{2001}$.

Getting an answer of $5\times10^{-15}$ when plugging in $n=13$ is just a matter of machine-precision-level errors adding up to something that the computer thinks is nonzero.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful solution! I'm curious to know whether the function in question is algebraic or transcendental. Could you provide any insight on this point? Thank you!

Comment: It depends entirely on your definition of "algebraic function". This function is built up out of compositions of rational functions and square roots, so to me it would be algebraic. Does it matter whether it is or not?

Comment: A reasonable answer to "is this algebraic or transcendental" is that it is _piecewise_ algebraic. Note that for $n<0$ but $n\approx 0$, $f(n)$ is not real, but that doesn't stop it from being algebraic. The underlying problem is that $\sqrt x$ means $|\sqrt x|$ here, so $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, which is only really piecewise algebraic, although we often gloss over this.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify the calculations, let $\,\frac{n^2 + \sqrt{n^4+16008n}}{2n} = a\,$ and $\,\frac{n^2 - \sqrt{n^4+16008n}}{2n} = b\,$ then $\,a+b = n\,$, $\,ab=-\frac{16008}{4n} = -\frac{16008}{4(a+b)} \iff 16008 = -4ab(a+b)\,$, and substituting these in $\,f(n)\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
2\big(f(n) + n\big) = a + \sqrt{a^2 + \frac{4(a+b)\cancel{a}b}{\cancel{a}}} = a + \sqrt{(a+2b)^2} = a + |a+2b|
\end{align}
$$

When $\,a+2b \ge 0\,$ the above reduces to $\,2f(n) + \cancel{2n} = \cancel{2(a + b)} \implies f(n) = 0\,$.

The condition for $\,a+2b \ge 0\,$ is:

$$
3n^2 \ge \sqrt{n^4+16008n} \;\;\iff\;\; 8 n^4 \ge 16008 n \;\;\iff\;\; n \ge \sqrt[3]{2001}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! Your solution was extremely helpful and easy to understand.